# Call parameterless CTOR and CTOR of base class from CTOR

Tags: c#

Need a little help. In the `ClassD` parameterized constructor I want to call the base contructor of `ClassA` AND the parameterless constructor of `ClassD`. Is this possible in C#?

Example code:

```
 public class ClassA
 {
    public ClassA(string message)
    {
    }

    public ClassA()
    {
    }

    ....
 }


 public class ClassD : ClassA
 {
     public string Name {get; }

     public ClassD() => this.Name = nameof(ClassD);


     public ClassD(string message) : base(message) //, this() -> gives me a compile error
     {
         // Is it possible to call ClassD paramterless in this CTOR?
     }
 }
```

Thx

Comment: "this() -> gives me a compile error" - what error?

Comment: The code you've got at the moment doesn't compile: 1) your `ClassD` doesn't derive from `ClassA`. 2) If you try to *make* it derive from `ClassA`, your parameterless constructor in `ClassD` won't compile because there isn't parameterless constructor in `ClassA`. Using `: this()` should call the parameterless constructor in the same class, but you need to get everything else sorted first.

Comment: But if you want to chain to *multiple* constructors, no, that's not possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry, yes I forgot the add the derive statement and the default constructor in `ClassA`. Thx, for the comment, I was looking for chaining the constructors as you supposed in your last comment. Then, I'll use a private `Init`-method and call it from both constructors of `ClassD`.

Comment: Reverse it. Make your less specific constructor `ClassD()` call `this(null)`, then make the other constructor handle the null case in the way you want the parameterless constructor to act. This is how _all_ overloads with more specific arguments should work; the real function is the one with all args, all overloads just call the real one with defaults for the missing args.

Comment: Or, y'know, in this case... just make a private init function that both constructors call after they call their respective base constructor, and put any common code in there.

Comment: @Nyerguds, thx. Your suggestion with `this(null)` fits perfect for me. Can you post your comment as answer. So that I can mark the question as solved. Thx.

Comment: It's worth noting that the private Init function approach has a significant downside though: it can't set readonly fields/properties. The "canonical constructor" approach is almost always better, although I've certainly seen times where that doesn't quite work out either.

Comment: @DaisyShipton True, but then you'll just have to copy that code into each one, I guess...

Comment: @Nyerguds: Yes, the rare cases where a canonical constructor doesn't work usually lead to code duplication for some parts :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of handling this. One, which is the simplest, is to just call the constructor with the argument from the one without with `null` as value, and put the actual initialization code in the one *with* the argument. That would give you:

```
 public class ClassD : ClassA
 {
     public string Name { get; }

     public ClassD() : this(null)
     { }

     public ClassD(string message) : base(message)
     {
         this.Name = nameof(ClassD);
     }
 }
```

**However**, this may lead to problems if the underlying behaviour of `ClassA` does not support this the same way. It's entirely possible that the `ClassA` constructor that takes a message arg is set up to throw an exception if it gets a `null` value in there. In that situation, a more reliable way of handling it would be to simply split off that common code you want to run from both constructors and put it into a new function, which you can then simply call from both constructors after the correct base constructor is called:

```
 public class ClassD : ClassA
 {
     public string Name { get; private set; }

     public ClassD() // will of course automatically call base()
     {
         this.Init();
     }

     public ClassD(string message) : base(message)
     {
         this.Init();
     }

     public void Init()
     {
         this.Name = nameof(ClassD);
     }
 }
```

In the end, though, which one is the best solution depends on the behaviour of `ClassA`. If you can be sure that its parameterless constructor acts the same as the other one with `null` as argument, the first approach is perfectly acceptable.

As Jon Skeet remarked in the comments, the init-function approach does have the drawback that you can't initialize read-only properties with it, since that only works from the constructors themselves, meaning that with that approach, any code to initialize such properties would inevitably need to be duplicated. As you see, the property has a private Setter now to remedy that.

Comment: About the drawback in your first example, you can pass in ´String.Empty´ instead of null

Comment: @MartinVerjans Bad idea, since that changes the behaviour. I could perfectly imagine the parameterless constructor filling in that message with a _default value_. You'd lose that if you put in an empty string instead, and you'll end up getting a meaningless empty response if that message is ever fetched. As I said though, all that depends entirely on the behaviour in `ClassA`.

Comment: Indeed I didn' think about that. Thanks for clarifying for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a middle(helper) class:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(string message)
    {
    }

    public ClassA()
    {
    }
}

public class HelperClass<T> : ClassA
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public HelperClass() => this.Name = nameof(T);

    public HelperClass(string message) : this()
    {
    }
}

public class ClassD : HelperClass<ClassD>
{
    public ClassD()
    {
    }

    public ClassD(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The point was that a call to `ClassD(string message)` would both fill in `this.Name` _and_ call the superconstructor `ClassA(string message)`. As far as I can see, that code will never call `ClassA(string message)` from the constructor `ClassD(string message)`.